# Rust: Combine two arrays to produce a new array containing tuples of references to all combinations of the source arrays

Tags: arrays, rust, vectorization

I have two arrays,

```
struct Point{
    position: (f32, f32),
}

struct Circle {
    position: (f32, f32),
    radius: f32,
}

type Points = [Option<Point>; 32];
type Circles = [Option<Circle >; 32];
```

And two traits,

```
trait Positioned {
    fn get_position(&self) -> (f32, f32);
}

trait Circular {
    fn get_radius(&self) -> f32;
}
```

And a function,

```
fn has_collision<P: Positioned, C: Positioned + Circular>(point: &P, circle: &C) -> bool {
    //check if point is within circle
    let (x, y) = point.get_position();
    let (cx, cy) = circle.get_position();
    let r = circle.get_radius();
    (x - cx).powi(2) + (y - cy).powi(2) <= r.powi(2)
}
```

The Points and Circles get spawned (become `Some`) with values. I want to iterate over them, test for collisions, and set them to None if they are collided.

One approach is a nested loop:

```
fn handle_collisions(points: &mut Points , circles: &mut Circles ) {
    for i in 0..points.len() {
        if let Some(point) = &points[i] {
            for j in 0..circles.len() {
                if let Some(circle) = &mut circles[j] {
                    if has_collision(point, circle) {
                        points[i] = None;
                        circles[i] = None;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I want to compare the performance of this with a different strategy - combine the points and circles into a single iterable of tuples, iterate over that, and then test for collisions and set them to None if they are collided.

How would I do this?

*edit 1:*

Here is an example that creates a new array that does not contain references to the original array:

```
fn vectorise(a: [i32; 3], b: [i32; 3]) -> [(i32, i32); 3*3] {
    let mut result = [(0, 0); 3*3];
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..3 {
            result[i*3+j] = (a[i], b[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

fn main() {
    let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
    let array2 = [4, 5, 6];
    let array3 = vectorise(array1, array2);
    println!("{:?}", array3);
}
```

The problem with this is that mutating array3 will not be reflected in array1 and array2. How do I solve this?

*edit 2:*

I have tried

```
fn vectorise<'c,>(a: &'c mut [i32; 2], b: &'c mut [i32; 2]) -> [(&'c mut i32, &'c mut i32); 4] {
    let mut result = [
        (&mut a[0], &mut b[0]),
        (&mut a[0], &mut b[1]),
        (&mut a[0], &mut b[2]),
        (&mut a[1], &mut b[0])
    ];
    result
}

fn main() {
    let mut array1 = [1, 2];
    let mut array2 = [4, 5];
    let mut array3 = vectorise(&mut array1, &mut array2);
    println!("{:?}", array3);
}
```

But I get the error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `b[_]` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src\main.rs:7:21
  |
2 | fn vectorise<'c,>(a: &'c mut [i32; 2], b: &'c mut [i32; 2]) -> [(&'c mut i32, &'c mut i32); 4] {
  |              -- lifetime `'c` defined here
3 |     let mut result = [
4 |         (&mut a[0], &mut b[0]),
  |                     --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
7 |         (&mut a[1], &mut b[0])
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
8 |     ];
9 |     result
  |     ------ returning this value requires that `b[_]` is borrowed for `'c`
```

Comment: Short answer: you are not getting better performance. In the best case, you'll get the same performance with more complicated code. In the worst case, you allocate the tuples (as a vector for instance) which will tear your performance down. If you want better performance, consider using a better collision algorithm than just testing every object against every other object.

Comment: @BlackBeans I am planning on using some kind of broad phase phase collision detection with a grid, i.e narrow down the objects that are in the same quadrant of the grid, then narrow down to the quadrant of that quadrant, and then test if the point is inside the circle. Also, I wanted to test another potential performance gain, sorting the vectorised object arrays so that None is at the end, and then breaking from the loop when it reaches the first None.

Comment: Is this a good idea? Could you please point me towards a better collision detection algorithm? Also, is my idea of using arrays of options instead of vectors that can be resized a good idea? Btw, the only purpose of this program is for me to practice writing performant code, because it interests me.